# Problema ao inserir carácater especial no Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Quando eu insiro alguma informação no Mysql através do formulario no meu sistema é salvo tudo errado no BD, os caracteres ç~´^`buga tudo, porém se insiro manualmente no phpmyadmin da certo. No HTML coloquei a tag meta charset UTF-8 e no php ini fala charset UTF-8

Para ler as infos do BD ta tudo correto, não da problema. Somente para inserir.

> Soluções Técnicas

É salvo o seguinte

> SoluÃ§Ãµes TÃ©cnica

Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Tenta inserir este código, no final, dentro do teu ficheiro que permite validar a base de dados:
`... resto do código ...
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET charecter_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET charecter_set_results=utf8');`

Caso estejas a utilizar `mysqli` ficaria:

```
mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

...

Experimenta também em todos os teus ficheiros `.php` inserir
 `header ('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, quando coloquei esse código deu erro na página. Coloquei o Header (Não deu erro, porem nao mudou nada :'(      )

Comment: O código inseriste no final da **página para validar a base de dados** certo? Estranho sempre funcionou comigo, que erro aparece?

Comment: is it this way ? <?php

$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'pedidos');

mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysqli_query('SET charecter_set_client=utf8');
mysqli_query('SET charecter_set_results=utf8');

?>

Comment: Onde tens `mysqli_query` esqueceste-te de colocar $conexao, neste caso fica assim no teu código `mysqli_query($conexao,"SET NAMES 'utf8');` `mysqli_query($conexao,'SET character_set_connection=utf8');` etc